# DNA extraction from parasitic worm

Tags: dna, parasitology

I have a part of a parasitic worm frozen at -20°C. Do you think that DNA extraction using DNeasy kit without any pre-treatment is sufficient for DNA extraction?

Or would you recommend bead beating / nitrogen?

I do not need high quality DNA. It is just for the identification via shotgun metagenomics (shotgun metagenomics because 1) the parasite identification failed so far via PCR/immunostaining and 2) there is some human traces as well).

I refer to " DNeasy Blood & Tissue". It comes with protocols for eucaryotic tissue. The sample is extracted from ejaculate. I also do not need a whole lot of DNA, about 100ng should be enough.